# AttributeError: 'PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtBoundSignal' object has no attribute 'Emt'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-signals

I've been trying to get a controller to work with signals (pyqtSignal), but I get this message when interacting with the GUI:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_signals.py", line 102, in <module>
    helper.Sinal.Emt.connect(PID.Imprime, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
AttributeError: 'PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtBoundSignal' object has no attribute 'Emt'
```

Would someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, here's the stripped down version of the code (main_signals.py):

```
# Import 3rd party libraries
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
import time
import pyqtgraph

# Import python standard modules
import sys 

# This file holds the MainWindow
import Plotter 

# Variables
T = [0]
R = [0]

# Disregard this function
def ReadChannel(channel):

# -----------------------------------------------------------------
class Ctrldr(QtGui.QMainWindow, Plotter.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.QOutput.clicked.connect(self.Calculo)        

    # Plotting
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, tuple)
    def Imprime(self, name, ptm):
        global T, R, W
        x, y = ptm
        R.append(y)
        self.graphicsView.plotItem.plot(T, R, pen='b')

    # Calculations
    def Calculo(self):
        global T

        t = time.clock()
        T.append(t)

        Read = ReadChannel(0)
        Helper.Sinal.emit("Sensor", (t, Read))
        Read = str(Read)
        self.QResult.setText(Read)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------
class Helper(QtCore.QObject):

    Sinal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, tuple)

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()

    def Emt(self, str, tuple):
        self.Sinal.emit(str, tuple) 

# -----------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    PID = Ctrldr()

    helper = Helper()
    helper.Sinal.connect(PID.Imprime)

    PID.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Tried to follow the examples in these 2 pages:

- [Plotting with pyqtgraph using external data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50314924/plotting-with-pyqtgraph-using-external-data)
- [Tutorial- Creating your own signals an slots](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pysidepyqt-tutorial-creating-your-own-signals-and-slots/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one that emits the signal is an object, in your Helper it is not an object, but the name of a class, so the solution is to create an object. For another `str` and `tuple` are reserved words that indicate data types, in the case of `pyqtSignal()` its use is correct since pyqtSignal () requires as parameters the types of data it will handle, but do not use it as arguments in `Emt()` since you overlapped his name.

```
# Import 3rd party libraries
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
import time
import pyqtgraph

# Import python standard modules
import sys 

# This file holds the MainWindow
import Plotter 

# Variables
T = [0]
R = [0]

# Disregard this function
def ReadChannel(channel):
    # some process
    return channel

# -----------------------------------------------------------------

# -----------------------------------------------------------------
class Helper(QtCore.QObject):
    Sinal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, tuple)
    def Emt(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.Sinal.emit(arg1, arg2) 


class Ctrldr(QtGui.QMainWindow, Plotter.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.QOutput.clicked.connect(self.Calculo)
        self.helper = Helper(self) # <--- object

    # Plotting
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, tuple)
    def Imprime(self, name, ptm):
        global T, R, W
        x, y = ptm
        R.append(y)
        self.graphicsView.plotItem.plot(T, R, pen='b')

    # Calculations
    def Calculo(self):
        global T

        t = time.clock()
        T.append(t)

        Read = ReadChannel(0)
        self.helper.Sinal.emit("Sensor", (t, Read))
        Read = str(Read)
        self.QResult.setText(Read)


# -----------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    PID = Ctrldr()

    helper = Helper()
    helper.Sinal.connect(PID.Imprime)

    PID.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks eyllanesc for the explanation and solution, the code works!